# Comparando dados retornados do BD

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, firebase

Estou com um problema que é o seguinte:

Ao ler os dados de um determinado nó do Firebase, recebo um número de Strings indeterminado. O nome de cada `String`, é o `ID` do User. Ao retornar esses dados, salvo eles em um `ArrayList`, para comparar se `Uid X` está na lista, assim: `arrayList.contains("Uid X")`.

No entanto, o retorno que tenho é um `true` ou um `false` para cada uma das `Strings`.
Como fazer para que **retorne apenas um true, ou um false** após verificar toda lista?

Comment: A princípio seria só mover todo o código pra dentro de um único `if`, não? Sugiro que você poste trechos do seu código - às cegas fica mais difícil pro pessoal responder!

Comment: Aproveite e [faça o tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), e veja mais informações de como perguntar [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

É só utilizar um ciclo:

```
boolean estaNaLista = false;
for(int i=0; i < arrayList.size();i++)
  if(arrayList.get(0).equalsIgnoreCase("Uid X"))
  {
    estaNaLista = true;
    break;
  }
//A este ponto o estaNaLista tera o valor que voce pretende.
```